nx fails after renaming target: Cannot find configuration for task
I have a working project configured for NX.
The project.json file contains (among others) a target named build, which builds our TypeScript application. When I call nx run build, I figure it must be this target that is run.

For testing purposes, I now rename that build target to abc.
Then, I invoke nx run abc, expecting that it will just work the same as it did before.
Instead, I am getting the error message

NX   Cannot find configuration for task myProject:abc

I must have misunderstood something about the working principle of NX, but what is it?

Somehow, this one was fixed by a reboot. I have no idea what else was changed.
